# Queue Jenkins Job step in TFS 2015 can't sync with Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, tfs

I can't make Queue Jenkins Job step neither get Jenkins build status nor get Console output.

I hoped to use step([$class: 'TeamCompletedStatusPostBuildAction']) in Jenkins Job, but developers were kind to put this info message:

```
NOTICE: You selected 'Set build completion status in TFS/Team Services' on your Jenkins job, but this option has no effect when calling the job from the 'Jenkins Queue Job' task in TFS/Team Services.
```

So how do I force TFS and Jenkins to communicate in this build step?

Note:
[Service Hook](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/marketplace/integrate/service-hooks/services/jenkins) works fine, but I want to get all the reports, progress, work items and notifications in TFS, so I would like to setup a full TFS build.

Comment: Did you check "Capture console output and wait for completion" option and "Capture pipeline output and wait for pipeline completion" option in "Jenkins Queue Job"? It works correct at my side.

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT yes, sure, [this is how this build step looks like in my TFS](https://www.dropbox.com/s/49nan1bzz76taad/Capture.JPG?dl=0)

Comment: Can you share the build logs?

Comment: For some reason I can't open logs from the build, I am trying to address this problem so I'll post them as soon as I get them.

Comment: I just realized that you are using Jenkins Queue Job with "Set build completion status in TFS/Team Services" post action together. Any reason that you use this post action in Jenkins Job? Enable the two option in Jenkins Queue Job task should be enough to get the console output and build status.

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT The reason is that there was no response about Jenkins status and I just thought that I need to add post build action step, now I see that this should be working without post build action

Comment: Glad to hear that. :)

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT Thank you for your help guys, I have found the weird fix for my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a weird fix to my problem that I can't really explain.

**Capture console output and wait for completion** only have to be chosen in *Queue Jenkins Job* step setup, and **Capture pipeline output and wait for pipeline completion** should be left unchecked.

Answer (score 2):

The **Queue Jenkins Job step**  queues a job on a Jenkins server. Full integration capabilities **require** installation of the [Team Foundation Server Plugin on Jenkins.](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Team+Foundation+Server+Plugin)  Make sure you have created Service Endpoint for Jenkins first.

And there is a detailed tutorial of this task in MSDN, you could refer this link: **[Jenkins Queue Job](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/build/jenkins-queue-job)**

Some other links about how to use this task and TFS integration with Jenkins:

- [A new Team Services build task to queue Jenkins jobs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/07/12/jenkins-queue-job-build-task/)
- [Visual Studio Team Services Integration with Jenkins](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/04/25/vsts-visual-studio-team-services-integration-with-jenkins/)

Comment: The thing is I have TFS Plugin installed and I am calling step([$class: 'TeamCompletedStatusPostBuildAction']) in my Jenkins Pipeline as tutorial suggests, but it seems not to be working from Jenkins pipeline, and I wasn't able to find any additional information except the two links you mentioned.

Comment: @Semant1ka Sorry not so familiar with ([$class: 'TeamCompletedStatusPostBuildAction']) in Jenkins. However about the task in TFS side, it's able to catch the Job status. Have your create Service Endpoint for Jenkins first? And set it correctly. If you need some tutorials just about the Queue Jenkins Job task in TFS , please refer this two links:  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/07/12/jenkins-queue-job-build-task/ & https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/04/25/vsts-visual-studio-team-services-integration-with-jenkins/

Comment: @Semant1ka If this `NOTICE: You selected 'Set build completion status in TFS/Team Services' on your Jenkins job, but this option has no effect when calling the job from the 'Jenkins Queue Job' task in TFS/Team Services.`  is the  prompting message in Jenkins side during your configuration,  afraid this is just not support for now. It's not related to TFS and Jenkins communication. You could add uservoice to Jenkins  team. The  Console output is in TFS build log.

Comment: Yes, I see this message in my pipeline. I am not a Jenkins expert either, but I just tried to play around with Service Hooks and noticed that I can't set up Jenkins Integration Level in hook settings to TFS Server Plugin, only Build-in Jenkins API available, so it seems that TFS can't see that I have a plugin installed, maybe it is also a problem. The second link you shared is very useful and it is related to TFS2017 while I am using TFS2015, maybe it doesn't have a full support of this feature.

Comment: >>However about the task in TFS side, it's able to catch the Job status - The problem is that it can't, build step just hanged after it has started a job on Jenkins, and I also can't see any build log, but it seems to be our TFS configuration problem. >>Have your create Service Endpoint for Jenkins first? - Well, it seems to be set up correctly, because when I configured it incorrectly it was not able to start any jobs.

Comment: You can trigger/queue a Jenkins job via POST to the Jenkins job API. You can invoke the API via powershell. This way you have option to run it to local PS command line without being in the TFS web UI.

Comment: @alltej It seems that is what Service Hook does, while in addition to triggering a Job I need its status, artifacts and etc.

Comment: @Semant1ka Yes, it would be same as Service hooks except that you don't need the TFS and the Jenkins plugin it will need. You can still get the status/output via the PS script.